# Dividend from ESOP to Cash - India

Tags: income-tax, india, dividend-reinvestment, espp

I'm Indian and working for a US organisation in India. I have been investing in the Employee Stock Purchase Plan (ESPP) for a while now. During the initial investment period, I had not opted for re-investment of dividends, due to which I have accumulated few US $. Now, I plan to transfer the funds(cash) in my bank a/c in India. Can you please help me with below questions?

1. How should I disclose it to the Indian tax authorities?
2. What forms should I be submitting to the tax authorities?

Thank you for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

> How should I disclose it to the Indian tax authorities?
>   What forms should I be submitting to the tax authorities?

You would need to declare this as "Income From Other Sources" and pay tax as per tax brackets. There no additional form to be filled, your ITR [Income Tax Return] is sufficient.

Comment: in addition to the tax bracket, does LTCG apply?

Comment: @Joko Long term capital gains will be applicable when you sell the stock. Not on divided income.

Comment: Fabulous, Dheer. Appreciate all your assistance.